# Задача на использование цикла

Tags: c#

Хотел бы узнать, как продолжить код. Задачу решить не могу. Нужно использовать цикл Do While.

```
double a, b, c;
a = 0;
Console.WriteLine("ВВедите числа, максимальный размер которого не превышает 30000, а кол-во чисел не превышает 1000");
b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

while (a <= 1000)
{
  if ((b <= 500) && (b % 3 == 0))
    a++;
  if (b >= 30000)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Слишком много чисел");
    break;
  }
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

Дальше не знаю как решить

> Составьте программу, которая последовательности натуральных чисел определяет количество чисел, меньших 500 и кратных 3. Программа получает на вход натуральные числа, количество введённых чисел неизвестно, последовательность чисел заканчивается числом 0 (0 - признак окончания ввода, не входит в последовательность). Количество чисел не превышает 1000. Введённые числа не превышают 30 000, Программа должна вывести одно число: количество натуральных чисел, меньших 500 и кратных
> (Проверкой ввод: `45, 20, 600, 0` вывод: `1`)

Comment: Вставьте задание текстом. И цикла `while-do` не существует, есть `while` и есть `do-while`. Отредактируйте вопрос.

Comment: Что делает Ваш код? Например, когда введено число `10`.

Comment: @Igor Ничего, просто вводит число, а дальше не дает ничего ввести

Comment: Я спросил не "что происходит с точки зрения пользователя", а "что делает код". Вы можете (должны) проследить, глазами или на листке бумаги, шаг за шагом, что делает Ваш (он же Ваш?) код. Когда сделаете это, приходите - продолжим.

Comment: Так я написал задание и там написано, что он должен делать. Сам я понял, что и как, но не знаю как это выразить в коде, по-этому и пришел за помощью.

Comment: То есть Вы не будете делать то, что я предложил?

Comment: Я немного не понял, что именно вы предложили

Comment: Я предложил Вам взять листок бумаги и выполнить на нем Ваш код построчно, одну строчку за другой, записывая значения всех пременных на каждом шаге.

Comment: как мне это поможет?

Comment: "как мне это поможет?" - Увидите.

Answer (score 0):

```
      int counter = 0;
      int i = 0;
      
      do {
        i++;
        
        int temp = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        if (temp == 0)
        {
          break;
        }
        else
        {
          if (temp <= 500 && temp % 3 == 0)
          {
            counter++;
          }
        }
      }
      while (i < 1000);
      
      Console.WriteLine(counter);
```

Comment: `do-while` же надо

Comment: @aepot все, поменял

Comment: Это не мой ответ, а ваш, и вы попробуйте протестировать, потому что: "во-первых" вы не правы, это не конец цикла, "во-вторых" счетчик не инкрементируется, когда 0, потому что `if (number > 0...)`. Но лучше пишите комментарий к тому посту, к которому он относится.

Comment: @aepotя бы написал, только у меня не было на это прав. А да, ошибся, все-таки у вас правильно.